# MATLAB: Passing data between two GUI's

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, handles

I have two GUI's with the figure-tags mainWindow and annotatorWindow. I want to pass data between the two windows. When I copy the data from mainWindow to annotatorWindow (see `copyData_Callback`), it works perfectly. But when I want to write the data back to mainWindow (see `saveData_Callback`), I get the error "Matrix indices must be full double". I'm not entirely sure what this even means, any help is appreciated. The code of interest is below.

```
CALLBACKS UNDER annotatorWindow



% --- Executes on button press in copyData.
function copyData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to copyData (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

h = findobj('Tag', 'mainWindow'); 

if ~isempty(h)
    pData = guidata(h)
    handles.UserData = pData.UserData 
end 

guidata(hObject, handles); 

return

% --- Executes on button press in saveData.
function saveData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to saveData (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

h = findobj('Tag', 'mainWindow'); 

if ~isempty(h) 
    guidata(h).UserData = handles.UserData 
end

guidata(hObject, handles); 

return
```

Comment: Please post (and read) the entire error message, it's quite explicit. The issue has nothing to do with passing data between GUIs. Your call to `guidata` in `saveData` is not valid. You are receiving the error because MATLAB thinks you're attempting to index `guidata` with `h`, which is an object and not an integer, and `guidata` is a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! To pass data between two GUI's, you can only ever *pull* data from a GUI. You can never write data to a GUI from another GUI. I created a function in `mainWindow` called `saveData` (see below). I then called the `saveData` function from `annotatorWindow` allowing me to pass data back and forth.

```
mainWindow

function saveData(hObject, handles)

h = findobj('Tag', 'annotatorWindow'); 

if ~isempty(h)
    aData = guidata(h) 
    handles.UserData = aData.UserData
end

guidata(hObject, handles); 


return 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
annotatorWindow

% --- Executes on button press in saveData.
function saveData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to saveData (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

h = findobj('Tag', 'mainWindow'); 

annotatorGUI('saveData', h, guidata(h));

return
```

Comment: This is not true: `you can only ever pull data from a GUI. You can never write data to a GUI from another GUI`